# Why does a gap appear between jQuery UI radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am theming a radio button using jQuery;

```
$(function() {
    $("#chart_switch").buttonset();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="chart_switch">
        <input type="radio" id="pie" name="chart_type" value="pie" checked="checked" /><label for="pie">Pie</label>
        <input type="radio" id="bar" name="chart_type" value="bar" /><label for="bar">Bar</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

The result:

[image]

What I don't understand is why a gap appears between the two options. I'm using Firefox 8.0 and also appears the same in Chrome (v15.0)

Comment: This is most likely to be caused by the CSS styling you have set on these elements. Could you post your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending an hour researching and trying all the solutions for this problem and then finally posting my question on SO, literally 5 minute later I discover that my jQuery needed updating...once I updated this, it appears as expected.

Answer (score 0):

remove margin and padding from the radio buttons via css and make them float left.
that's all I can say without seeing the css you have applied.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK on my machine (no gap).  It might be the UI theme you have chosen.